# Android studio: v 2.3.1 Debugger hanging

Tags: android-studio, debugging, freeze

Yesterday all was fine now this morning ...Wherever I set a breakpoint, my debugger will hang with a message:
**"Waiting until last debugger command completes".**
I thought upgrading to latest version would fix it but did not make a differen

I tried with:

- Android emulators
- LG V20
- Genymotion (Google Nexxus 5x 7.0)
- Genymotion (Samsung Galaxy S7 3.0)

**UPDATE:**

Ok now this is odd, I see its only hanging in one Class file, it figures its the class I really need to step through....if I just run the app it seems to execute fine through that same class...why would this be?

Comment: are you using emulator? or your phone? most likely problem with it, though what hardware are you using/do you emulate?

Comment: @Myszsoda I updated question with info

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the class that you are trying to set your break point in, will not allow you to do that because it's blocking the thread.